# Calculating end date while skipping holidays + Joda time

Tags: java, jodatime

I would like to calculate *end date* (and time) of an event. I know *starting date* and *duration* (in minutes). But:

1. I have to skip holidays - non-recurrent situation
2. I have to skip weekends - recurrent situation
3. I have to *not* count working time (e.g: from 8:00am till 5:00pm) - recurrent situation, but with finer granularity

Is there a simple way to achieve these cases using Joda time library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jodatime will help you -a lot I'd say-, but you'll need to write the logic yourself, a loop  skipping some entire days and some times of the day. Not very simple, neither very complex, it seems to me.

Comment: Marking as accepted answer, because it's true. According to my researches, there is no simple solution. And Jodatime is definetly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [Holiday calculation](http://objectlabkit.sourceforge.net/) project? it is featured in the Related projects from jodatime and could be useful

Comment: Looks really good. But I still don't know how to handle working hours. I basically need to fast-forward given date by N-minutes. Skipping working hours, holidays, etc...

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define "holidays".  Not every locale has the same ones, so this has to be made generic and pluggable.

I don't think it's "simple".

Comment: In my case holidays are stored in a database. But I wanted to point out that I cannot use: if(dayofweek() == 7) { skip(); }

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I use. `dtDateTimes` can contain your pre-defined holiday dates (e.g. UK Bank Holidays) and `dtConstants` can contain recurring things you'd like to match against, like `DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY`.

```
/**
 * Returns a tick for each of
 * the dates as represented by the <code>dtConstants</code> or the list of <code>dtDateTimes</code>
 * occurring in the period as represented by begin -> end.
 * 
 * @param begin
 * @param end
 * @param dtConstants
 * @param dtDateTimes
 * @return
 */
public int numberOfOccurrencesInPeriod(final DateTime begin, final DateTime end, List<Integer> dtConstants, List<DateTime> dtDateTimes) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (DateTime current = begin; current.isBefore(end); current = current.plusDays(1)) {
        for (Integer constant : dtConstants) {
            if (current.dayOfWeek().get() == constant.intValue()) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        for (DateTime dt : dtDateTimes) {
            if (current.getDayOfWeek() == (dt.getDayOfWeek())) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

    }
    return counter;
}

/**
 * Returns true if the period as represented by begin -> end contains any one of
 * the dates as represented by the <code>dtConstants</code> or the list of <code>dtDateTimes</code>
 *  
 * @param begin
 * @param end
 * @param dtConstants
 * @param dtDateTimes
 */
public boolean isInPeriod(final DateTime begin, final DateTime end, List<Integer> dtConstants, List<DateTime> dtDateTimes) {
    return numberOfOccurrencesInPeriod(begin, end, dtConstants, dtDateTimes) > 0;
}
```