# Scheduling software data structures?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Just a question for the experienced programmers.

I'm creating a scheduling software.

I have a start date and a number of days it takes to complete the task and I want to calculate the end date.

Easy enough.

However, I want to subtract weekends and holidays.

My instinct is to have two lists, one of days that have passed and one for the weekends/holidays to skip, and for each day that passes check to see if it's a holiday or a weekend and skip it.

But that seems like it would scale exponentially.

Wondering how an experienced programmer would implement this.

Comment: looks a lot like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751302/calculating-end-date-while-skipping-holidays-joda-time and I think I'd give you the same answer. Joda Time and there's no simple path ;-)

Comment: also check http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/ and http://objectlabkit.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: but it seems that basically, what you need is a table of holidays and a function that returns, given a date range, how many weekends (any calendar / joda will give you that) and holidays (your hand-made table of holidays) are in there :-)

Comment: It doesn't scale exponentially it looks like `O(N*M)` - for each of `N` work days to be done, you need to check if the date of the date is on a list of `M` holidays. I think with little tweaks it can be brought to be `O(N^2)` or maybe `O(N)` practically.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

```
We have list of Holiday in a table.
We have start date.
we have number of days to complete task.

Initialize counter to 0
Loop counter till no of days to complete is reached
   1. Increment start date with one.
   2. Skip 4 if it belongs to Holiday.
   3. Skip 4 if it is weekend.
   4. increment the counter
Print start date as End date
```