# Java Bowling Program - Adding 10th Frame

Tags: java, class, loops, methods, junit

I am currently working on a bowling program and have most of it working. I have a junit test file called BowlingGameTest, a class called Game that deals with most of the scoring, and a class called Play that deals with most of the game itself. The only thing that needs added as far as I know is the 10th frame specifics. Right now, if I "bowl a strike" then the 10th frame just ends like frames 1-9 would. However, it needs to give me another bowl, and based off of what I "bowl" the next throw, possibly another bowl too. What would be the best way to implement this for a 10th frame?

Here is what I have so far in my Play class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Play {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game g = new Game();
        int i;
        int PinsDown1;
        int PinsDown2;
        int PinsDown3;

        for (i=1; i<11; i++)
        {
            PinsDown1 = ThrowBall(0); //1st try
            System.out.println("Frame " + i + " Throw 1" + " knocked down is " + PinsDown1);
            if(PinsDown1 == 10)
            {
                g.roll(10);
                System.out.println("Congratulations, you bowled a strike!");
                System.out.println();
            }
            else
            {
                PinsDown2 = ThrowBall(PinsDown1); //2nd try
                System.out.println("Frame " + i + " Throw 2" + " knocked down is " + PinsDown2);
                g.roll(PinsDown1);
                g.roll(PinsDown2);
                if (PinsDown1+PinsDown2 == 10)
                    System.out.println("Congratulations, you bowled a spare!");
                    System.out.println();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Final score is " + g.score() );

    }  //*** end main ***

    public static int ThrowBall(int PinsDown)
    {
        int standing = 10-PinsDown;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  down = rand.nextInt(standing+1); 
        return down;
    }

}  //*** End class ***
```

Comment: Perhaps make your own [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) implementation. If a tenth is appropriate, provide it, otherwise provide only the ninth. See [this Answer by Dave Swartz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22110692/642706) about a custom iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Consider changing your for loop to a while loop.  Use your variable i as frame counter and add a condition to break out of the loop if >=10 and not a strike.

Comment: this is a low quality answer. Please provide relevant examples of how to solve the issue. As your answer is currently stated, it should be a comment only.

Comment: I think it's a rather fine answer.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I think it should be a comment